# Compile C++ code via C# class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, compilation

I use this method to compile C++ file in VS. But even i provide the correct file it returns false. Can any one help me...
This is class called CL

```
class CL
{
    private const string clexe = @"cl.exe";
    private const string exe = "Test.exe", file = "test.cpp";
    private string args;

    public CL(String[] args)
    {
        this.args = String.Join(" ", args);
        this.args += (args.Length > 0 ? " " : "") + "/Fe" + exe + " " + file;
    }

    public Boolean Compile(String content, ref string errors)
    {
        if (File.Exists(exe))
            File.Delete(exe);
        if (File.Exists(file))
            File.Delete(file);

        File.WriteAllText(file, content);

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = clexe;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = this.args;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc.Start();
        //errors += proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        errors += proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        bool success = File.Exists(exe);

        return success;
    }
}
```

This is my button click event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content = "#include <stdio.h>\nmain(){\nprintf(\"Hello world\");\n}\n";
        string errors = "";

        CL k = new CL(new string[] { });
        if (k.Compile(content, ref errors))
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Errors are : ", errors);
    }
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: That looks remarkably like C# code - why does your question text ask about C++ when the question is tagged C#?

Comment: In message box it shows as "fatal error c1510: cannot load language resource clui.dll"

Comment: The Code is C# but he wants to compile C++ files with it. Thats exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: Is the environment set up? You'll need everything you'll find in vsvars32.bat in Visual Studio\Common\Tools or at least PATH, INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH. I don't know if programs you're debugging inherit this from Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually I try to compile C++ program using C# application.

Comment: Still i unable to do it...... :(

Comment: If it's not the environment then I don't have any good ideas. You could try putting the full path to cl.exe in rather than just cl.exe to see if that makes any difference - it could be it's using arg[0] to try and locate clui.dll, although that still ought to get set correctly if it's executed through the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Visual Studio installation folder there should be the following path:

```
VC\bin\x86_amd64\1033\1033
```

There should be a `clui.dll` in this path. Copy it to the parent folder (`VC\bin\x86_amd64\1033`). This should solve your problem.

I took the solution from http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/108528/command-line-issue-when-building-for-64bit-in-32bit-with-cl-exe:

Comment: you mean to add the clui.dll to debug folder. I done it. But still same error. Is there anything i need to set

Comment: I expect it'll be looking for clui.dll either in a locale-specific directory relative to cl.exe or to something in your path. I'd open a Visual Studio command prompt (or run vsvars32.bat in a regular command prompt) then try running your built .exe from there, preferably away from any cl.exe or clui.exe that you've copied around, to see if it's just an environment problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not relevant, but I think you miss a space in your command line...

```
this.args += (args.Length > 0 ? " " : "") + "/Fe" + exe + " " + file;
```

right after the `"/Fe"`